# How to call Rest Webservice in iPhone using the following details

Tags: iphone, rest, webservices-client

I have a URL which supports REST WebService

https://xxx.yyy.zzz/abc/xyz.svc (added some masking)

the following operations are supported:

**Get**

**Create**

**Update**

**getList**

**$metadata**

the following options are supported:

**$top**            (-1 get’s all records)

**$select**

**$filter**         (only the ‘eq’ and the ‘and’ operators are supported)

Now i need to test the above Operation in iPhone.
For Simple SOAP Request we creat NSURLRequest and set all parameters , but here things are confusing, dont know how to use these above Operations and Options.

If anyone know some info please share

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got to know myself,

The Operations like Get, Create , Update and getList which are supported by my server can be used the following way

**https://xxx.yyy.zzz/abc/xyz.svc/Get**

Here Get can be replaced with Create, Update and getList.

This URL need to be used in your NSURLConnection with no Header Fields. You may get the response as XML/JSON which needs to be parsed.

Now for the Options

https://xxx.yyy.zzz/abc/xyz.svc/get()?$filter=spras eq 'D' and land1 eq 'AI'

Here i am using the $filter option , so **get** becomes **get()**

I am still not sure on what spras and land1, i am still working on this, i will share more info once i complete the implementation.

If others have more info please share.

This [link](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/odataexplorer/) provides a great place to start. Select any public OData Services and check out the examples and observe the link after you create you Query.

Thanks

Comment: That really looks just plain wrong. The HTTP Method should determine if it is Get/Put/Delete/Post not the URL.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood : Here Get is the operation that is supported by the server, I think it is not the Get of type Get/POST , let me know if i am wrong

Comment: if it is part of the link you are doing it wrong, you should let it be determined by the HTTP method

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood : i referred this link for examples http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/odataexplorer/